# Angular2 syntax in W3C HTML Validator

Tags: html, angular, w3c-validation

Angular 1.x allowed to put elements in HTML, which were not known for [W3C HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/). Workaround for this was to add `data-` prefix and write e.g. `data-ng-repeat` instead of `ng-repeat`.

In the current Angular 2 version we have a different syntax. This syntax is also case-sensitive, e.g. we have to use `ngClass`, not `ngclass`.

All brackets used in Angular2 are causing HTML validation errors. Fortunately there is also a canonical form, so instead of `(event)` we can go with `on-event`, instead of `[property]` we can go with `bind-property` and instead of `[(ngModel)]` we can use `bindon-ngModel`. All those things work with `data-` prefix.

But what with directives like `*ngFor`, `*ngIf` and `*ngSwitch`? What with template variables `#variable`? Do you know any workaround in order to make Angular 2 template with those things a valid HTML in W3C Validator?

Comment: you want to know how we can define `*ngFor` and so on by another way ? like on-event ?

Comment: I've edited my questions. I would like to use W3C Validator with my Angular 2 templates. Is the ignoring things like `*ngFor` the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the canonical form. The `*` is for structural directives which can be used with the `<template>` tag. With `*` the template is implicit, but you can always use an explicit template tag instead and with this the canonical forms of the bindings you listed above.

See `* and <template>` in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for something like this! Full chapter name is "* and <template>", you have just "* and ".

Comment: Sorry, was a formatting issue. SO swallowed the rest.