# Angular2 and W3C HTML validation

Tags: html, angular, w3c-validation, angular2-directives, angular-template

I'm developing an app with Angular2 and since I use directives or custom tags in the code, it can't be validated by W3C HTML validation.

For example if I use `<my-component>` element or `*ngIf` directive or some one way/two way binding elements, such as `(click)` or `[(ngModel)]`, it can't be valid for any W3C validator.

I think I should replace them with elements that are validable.

So, starting from [Angular2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template), I created the following summary for replacement:

- (event)                     -->         data-on-event
- [property]                  -->         data-bind-property
- [(ngModel)]                 -->         data-bindon-ngModel
- *ngFor="let i of items"     -->         data-template="ngFor let i of items"
- *ngIf="condition"           -->         data-template="ngIf:condition"

Is this the right way for every element of my list to write code that is compliant with W3C standards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 syntax in W3C HTML Validator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480893/angular2-syntax-in-w3c-html-validator)

Comment: That doesn't reply to my interrogative sentence at the end of my post...

Answer (score 0):

You can "unpack" the *ngFor (and so on) syntactic sugar.

An excellent explanation of this is actually offered in the Tour of Heroes angular 2 tutorial (looking for link...)

Ah found it.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template

Go to the "* and Template" section.

Comment: Ehm... your link is the link i posted in my question!

Comment: Completely nonsense downvote. No explanation and six months after the fact (you should not be allowed to downvote outside of 30 days, another flaw in the SO over-eager downvote system).